# How to model mapping between two images? (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to create realistic like license plates, I write a code to create them but they are not very realistic, for this I want to model mapping between real license plates and fake ones and then map fake license plates to convert them to realistic images.

My fake license plate:

[image: Fake License Plate]

And this is its correspondence in real world:

[image: Real License Plate]

I want to find a suitable mapping that convert fake LPs to real one, but as you can see the mapping is not just spatial (I cannot model it just by a homography transformation). How could I model this kind of mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect task for GAN networks. Check this project for example [CycleGAN](https://github.com/junyanz/CycleGAN).

Comment: I don't know actually GAN is suitable for my task or not because of two reasons. First, my dataset is about 10000 image which is not really big for GAN networks and secondly, I should use conditional GAN because I want to know my license plate numbers which even increase the need for data. Now do you think GAN is suitable?
But CycleGAN results is awesome :)

Comment: 10k samples  of each image type (input and desired), should be quite enough for CGAN, also you can do augmentation.  And it will transform style of your input image to your output image. Output images will contain same information as on input images but will look realistic. So, I still think it is reasonable to try.

Comment: I think I should use pix2pix GAN right? because in Cycle GAN the context (which is license plate number here) is not important for the network, but in pix2pix it is.

Comment: I did similar task, CycleGAN worked better than pix to pix. And context was transfered fine. Anyway, you can try both it will take 1-2 days to check which network works better.